# AoInitialize - "ArcGIS product not specified." 10.1 Student Edition single use license

Tags: arcgis-10.1

I have a Student Edition of ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop Advanced.  My license is set up on my machine as single use.  I am trying to initialize the license in ArcObjects, however I get the following error:

"ArcGIS product not specified.  You must first bind to an ArcGIS version prior to using any ArcGIS components."

This occurs when I call AoInitialize.IsProductCodeAvailable() which doesn't make sense, since that is how you figure out what license to initialize in the first place.  Here is my code:

```
public static esriLicenseStatus Intialize(
        ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.esriLicenseProductCode esriLicenseProductCode)
    {
        IAoInitialize aoInitialize = new AoInitialize();
        esriLicenseStatus esriLicenseStatus = 
            aoInitialize.IsProductCodeAvailable(esriLicenseProductCode);

        if (esriLicenseStatus == ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.esriLicenseStatus.esriLicenseAvailable)
            esriLicenseStatus = 
                aoInitialize.Initialize(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeAdvanced);

        return esriLicenseStatus;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?  Does this have to do with it being Student Edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code using the [`RuntimeManager`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//004600000022000000) class, makes it much simpler:

```cs
    if (ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.ActiveRuntime == null)
        ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.BindLicense(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.EngineOrDesktop);
```

You'll need to add a reference to the `ESRI.ArcGIS.Version` assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too. This exception throws when I call `AoInitialize.Initialize()`.

I use WPF and winform MapView control.

This exception is thrown when I call `.Initialize()` in BackgroundWorker in splash window.
I bind product code to runtime in application start up and Initialize method run successfully.

```
Private Sub Application_Startup_1(sender As Object, e As StartupEventArgs)
        If Not ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.Bind(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.Engine) Then
            If Not ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.Bind(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.Desktop) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to bind to ArcGIS runtime. Application will be shut down.")
            End If
        End If
        Dim _initialize As New AoInitializeClass()
        _initialize.Initialize(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeEngineGeoDB)
        _splash = New SplashScreen()
        _splash.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

All thing become ok.